# Mathematical constant

Tags: number-theory, constants

Does there exists any important complex mathematical constant ?

It is known that there exist a large number of mathematical constants that are real numbers, like:
$$\pi, e, \phi, ...$$

Here is the link for much more of them:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant

I have never seen and could not find any constant written as:
$$c = \alpha + \beta i$$
$$i = \sqrt{-1}$$
$$\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb{R}$$
Why ?

---

What I mean is that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can't be also a combination of any other well known constants, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be in some way unique like $\pi$ is unique for themselves and is strongly connected with circle, or like Feigenbaum constants that are strongly connected with bidfurcation and can't be rewriten as combination of any other constatns.

Comment: $\pi +ie$.{}{}{}{}{}

Comment: Just I want to say $i=\sqrt {-1}$ is not correct notation. Actually, using $i^2=-1$ is correct. Because, $\sqrt {•}$ is used to get square roots from nonnegative real numbers

Comment: I'd say the most important complex constant is simply the imaginary unit $i$. That's why mathematicians consider Eulers Identity $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ the most beautiful formula, since it combines the $5$ most important mathematical constants.

Comment: @vitamind: I think you meant $e^{i\pi} +1 = 0$. And I see $5$ constants there.

Comment: @lonestudent why isn't $i=\sqrt -1$ a correct notation? I see you edited your comment, but the square root is just a definition that one may extend to the complex numbers.

Comment: @lonestudent It's fine to write $i = \sqrt{-1}$, as long as you correctly interpret it as saying that $i$ is *a* square root of $-1$, and keep in mind that there's an arbitrary choice there (since there isn't a notion of "positive" or "negative" in the complex numbers to give us a preferred branch of the square root).

Comment: @DanielHast You can be right. But I saw that there is no such notation in three wiki encyclopedias.  "Complex number - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number "Imaginary number - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number "Imaginary unit - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit   That's what the teacher told us at our school.  I'm not an expert.  Yes what you said seems to make sense.  (Maybe what you say in academic books is written, only I have no information)

Answer (score 6):

You could argue the most important number in complex analysis is $2\pi i$, because of its appearance in the residue theorem.

Complex roots of unity, i.e. $\{e^{2\pi iq}|q\in\Bbb Q\}$, are also very important, partly because of their role in the theory of polynomials, partly because of complex analysis again. In particular, you often see results of the form $\oint_Cf(z)dz=(1-e^{2\pi is})\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$, which allow us to calculate some integrals of the form $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ with a keyhole contour. (If the upper limit is instead finite, doghole contours may encounter the same phenomenon.) You may wish to argue, then, that $1-e^{2\pi is}$ or its reciprocal is therein of more fundamental importance, for suitable $s$, than is $e^{2\pi is}$.